# jQuery: Get first object in array after Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get the first object returned by the ajax call before doing the each() loop through it. Here's the code that works for the each:

```
$.each(obj.DATA, function(indexInArray, value) {
            var depts = value[departmentListIndex];
            console.log("test",depts);
          });
```

What I'd like to do is this:

```
$.each.first(obj.DATA, function(indexInArray, value) {
            var depts = value[departmentListIndex];
            console.log("test",depts);
          });
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
VM1172:38 Uncaught TypeError: $.each.first is not a function
```

doing a $.get(obj.DATA)..... doesn't work either.

Comment: If `obj.DATA` is an array, a simple `obj.DATA[0]` would get you the first one. And yes, `$.each.first` is not a function.

Comment: There are two levels to the objects returned in the array. I used obj.DATA[0][14] and that worked. Thanks

Comment: Glad it helped.. I thought I did not understand your problem at first. If you want to iterate the first array with `.each`, you can do it like `$.each(obj.DATA[0], ...)`

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each.first(obj.DATA[0], function(indexInArray, value) {
    var depts = value[departmentListIndex];
    console.log("test",depts);
});
```